# Django BooleanField(default=False) Confusion

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Can anyone help me out here? I am inserting data into my postgreSQL DB.

admin_created is a booleanfield set to false by default. I've provided a true value for the first workout, but left the second workout blank for the booleanfield. Based on my understanding it should automatically be set to false, but i'm getting the error message below. Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
#.sql

INSERT INTO main_app_workout(name, description, admin_created)
  VALUES
    ('Yoga', 'Roll up your yoga mat and discover the combination of physical and mental exercises that have hooked yoga practitioners around the globe.', 'True');

INSERT INTO main_app_workout(name, description)
  VALUES
    ('Boxing', 'Ready to get your sweat on? Learn the six basic punches to build the foundation of an experienced boxer.');


#models.py

class Workout(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField()
    exercises = ManyToManyField(Exercise, blank=True)
    admin_created = models.BooleanField(default=False)


#Error code 
psql:db/create_main_exercises.sql:49: ERROR:  23502: null value in column "admin_created" of relation "main_app_workout" violates not-null constraint
```

EDIT:
Thank you all for the comments. My solution to this problem was to provide true values for the admin_created for the seeded data. In addition I changed the admin_created field to

`admin_created = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)`

When I create new instances of the model in Django it automatically sets it to False.

Comment: Is `Workout` model managed by django? As far as I know, `default` is for when django manages the model itself, and it does not reflect in the column at the database level. So default here will only kick in if you use ORM

Answer (score 0):

Django is builded to use the ORM, if you are doing this insertion manually, Django can't set the defaul value for you, so will be passed NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The field based constraints are only placed at the code level in django not at the DB level.
So if you 'll create a object in django programmatically you 'll not face this issue. But when created using SQL you 'll face this issue.

Only a few constraints are available that you can apply at the DB level that too post django 2.2.

Check the constraints documentation for django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/)